# Django - Else Syntax Error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following code on my views.py

```
def visao_produto(request, produto_visualizado, categoria_produto):
    produto = Camisa.objects.get(slug=produto_visualizado)
    categoria_desejada = categoria_produto.replace("_"," ")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LojaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            add_to_cart(request, produto_visualizado.id, produto_visualizado.tipo, produto_visualizado.categoria)
            get_cart(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = LojaForm()

    return render_to_response('loja/produto_visualizado.html', { 'produto' : produto, 'categoria_desejada' : categoria_desejada, 'form' : form }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

But my template is returning the following error:

SyntaxError at /loja/Minecraft/minecraftsteve/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 34)

Line 34, on this case, is the line of the last else, before "print form.errors", which is there because i was trying to solve this problem. I'm not sure if the rest of the code is correct, but right now i'm just stuck on this problem.

I have imported everything and i really don't know what is possible to be wrong in an else statement.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error is my best guess, right above the else line in question.  Django sometimes spits these out as simple syntax issues. Immediate other things to check (that don't seem present) are a missed closing quote, comma or  parentheses, though I really don't see any of those (which leads me to indent errors).

I've gone over your code and even copied/pasted with some dummy stuff into my test server, and I can't find anything "wrong" with what shows up here on screen.  So I'd start by making sure there's not an issue where you used 4 spaces instead of tab or vice versa.  That would be covered up by Stack's HTML formatting so we can't necessarily see that.